# GWT: Is it OK to edit the same proxy multiple times?

Tags: gwt, gwt2, requestfactory

I'm using GWT 2.4 with RequestFactory but not still everything is clear for me.

In [this](http://fascynacja.wordpress.com/2011/04/17/exciting-life-of-entity-proxies-in-contexts-of-requestfactory/) article author wrote about situation when we used an entity proxy with one instance of `RequestContext` and want to reuse (`edit()`) this entity proxy with other instance of `RequestContext`:

> It cannot be edited because it has already a requestContext assigned.
>   If you want to change it you must retrieve instance of this entity
>   from server again

But I'm getting no exceptions when I execute this code:

```
RequestContext newRequest1 = factory.myRequest();
newRequest1.edit(proxy);
RequestContext newRequest2 = factory.myRequest();
newRequest2.edit(proxy);
```

The problems (exception) described by autor pop up when I run this version:

```
RequestContext newRequest1 = factory.myRequest();
MyProxy edited = newRequest1.edit(proxy);
RequestContext newRequest2 = factory.myRequest();
newRequest2.edit(edited);
```

So it seems that only editable copy returned by `edit()` is directly related with RequestContext instance.

In that case is there something wrong in approoach in which I keep one instance of (uneditable/frozen) proxy in my edit view and each time user clicks "edit" button I `edit()` it with new fresh RequestContext? Or should I obtain fresh instance of proxy each time too?

Getting new instance of proxy seems a bit awkward for me but I guess reusing one proxy instance may cause some issues related to sending delta of changes to server?

So to rephrase the question: it a good practice to reuse single instance of proxy with multiple `RequestContexts`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no problem editing the same proxy twice (or more), as long as there's only a single editable instance at a time (your first code snippet should throw; if it's not then it's a bug; it could work if you don't keep references on both the `RequestContext` and the edited proxy).

Note that RequestFactory sends only the modified properties to the server, but it does so by diff'ing with the non-editable instance passed to `edit()`; so you should try to use the most recent instance as possible to keep your server-side/persisted data as close to your client-side data as possible (could seem obvious, but can lead to some *surprises* in practice: if you see *foo* on the client but have *bar* on the server, you'll keep the *bar* on the server-side until you modify the property on the client-side to something other than *foo*)

Comment: Thanks for clearing up, Thomas! And there is no way to say to proxy: update yourself from server? The only way is to get a fresh proxy with the same id from the server side? PS. Yeah, my snippet really didn't throw exception. Maybe it's a bug or some very specific circumstances.

Comment: Or isn't there a way to say to proxy: synchronize yourself with modified editable proxy on client so that you have not to be loaded again from server to be up-to-date?

Comment: No. That was the case in early versions of RequestFactory (2.1M1 at least), where there was only one frozen instance that was updated each time it was part of a request, but it was removed. I believe that was because you can request a _partial_ bean, so what should be done with the properties that were previously retrieved but weren't retrieved in the latest request? Removed with the risk of breaking the app, or kept with the risk of being outdated, with the proxy possibly being in an invalid state?